# ndk filter does not work on android modules

Tags: android, gradle

I'm using the following code in my gradle file, it makes my apk file smaller.

```
release {
            minifyEnabled true
            debuggable false
            jniDebuggable false
            renderscriptDebuggable false
            pseudoLocalesEnabled false
            zipAlignEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            ndk {
                abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "armeabi"
            }
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
```

and it does. the problem is, when I'm adding the same code in the library I added to the project as a module, it does not work. it's like the code

```
ndk {
                    abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "armeabi"
                }
```

is not effective on library.